# How to use variables in Prolog query shell?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, declarative, prolog-toplevel

I know that I can use variables in Prolog shell (something like using '$' character, I think...but I don't remember...)

If I execute the following query it seems to work fine:

```
?- leggiFile('dataggare.txt', ListaTesto), tokenizzaLista(ListaTesto, TokenizedList, 1).
ListaTesto = [68, 117, 114, 97, 110, 116, 101, 32, 105|...],
TokenizedList = [t(1, [68, 117, 114, 97, 110, 116, 101]), t(-1, [32]), t(2, [105, 108]), t(-1, [32]), t(3, [77, 101, 100|...]), t(-1, [44]), t(-1, [32]), t(4, [...|...]), t(..., ...)|...]
```

But if I try to execute the two query **leggiFile/2** and **tokenizzaLista/2** separately, in this way go into error:

```
?- leggiFile('dataggare.txt', ListaTesto).
ListaTesto = [68, 117, 114, 97, 110, 116, 101, 32, 105|...].

?- tokenizzaLista($ListaTesto, TokenizedList, 1).
ERROR: variable `ListaTesto' does not exist
```

Why? it seems to me very strange. What am I missing?

Comment: if tokenizzaLista is DCG based, you can use phrase_from_file

Comment: no, this is not a DCG based

Comment: `$` is not guaranteed to work always. It is intended as a quick hack (for a user). The proper way is simply to `asserta` it into the database under a functor name of your choosing: e.g. `asserta( sym(Name,Val) )` and then `sym(Name,Val)` to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
?- open('uty.pl',read,S).
S = <stream>(0x236d4d0).

?- read($S,K).
K = (:-module(uty, [atoi//2, cache_file/2, cache_path/4, call_nth/2, cat/2, count_solutions/2, ... / ...|...])).

?- read($S,K).
K = (:-reexport(nb_uty, [ (<<)/2, (>>)/2, ++ / 2, (**)/2])).
...
```

but I'm not sure if garbage collection could disturb...

[Documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%272.8%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/topvars.html%27%29%29) states

> Bindings resulting from the successful execution of a top-level goal are asserted in a database if they are not too large.

Comment: I have change my question because I had made a series of errors in the original one. Still don't work but now I have post the real problem...it seems to me strange because I think that I am using the correct syntax to use variables in Prolog shell

Comment: I think your variables are too large.

Comment: maybe this is the reason because ListaTesto contains all the ASCII character of a txt file...I will try with a very short file